# Call a method from dll c#

Tags: c#, methods, dll, windows-phone

I have a dll which contains methods like

```
public static void newSession(string email, string pass)
public static dynamic checkData(int imei, string name)
```

The dll alredy added to project and to "using".
First, at the beginning of program, I should to call "newSession". And after it - "checkData" for the Login button. 
But I don't understand how and where it could be done. Can someone help me do it?

P.S. It is a Windows Phone application

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some more information: I assume the dll is written in c# too? And you added the `using` statements for the correct namespace? So can you show the code of the dll and the code where you try to call it? In which class are those methods defined?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  see my edit and answer ;)

Comment: @AtmaneELBOUACHRI I'm currently not able to review suggested edits, but I'm sure your edit will be rejected. It's not a good idea to add code to a question of another user. When we want to help him/her, we need to see what _s/he did_, not what you _guess_ s/he did.

Comment: @René I want just help him

Comment: @AtmaneELBOUACHRI I understand that. No offence. Just wanted to help you to avoid edit mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
using yournamespace;
  class MyClass2
    {

        void MyMethod()
        {
            MyClass.newSession("Whatever", "Whatever");
            MyClass.checkData(0, "Whatever");

        }
    }
```